# EPERM while renaming directory in node js randomly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fs

I gotta a requirement from which I need to remove the Backup folder and I need to rename the processor as Backup and I need to Create a Processor folder again and need to send a response to the user. For this I am using below code.

```
fsExtra.remove('app/Backup', function(err, result) {
    if(err){
        console.log("Err in removing Backup folder "+JSON.stringify(err));
    }else{      
        fs.rename('app/Processor','app/Backup', function(err, result) {
            if(err){
                console.log("Err in renaming folder "+JSON.stringify(err));
            }else{
                fs.mkdir('app/Processor', function(err, result) {
                    if(err){
                        console.log("Err in mk Backup folder "+JSON.stringify(err));
                    }else{
                       res.send("success");
                    }
                });
            }
        }); 
    }
});
```

Many times its working as expected but at one point it giving below error

```
Err in renaming folder {"errno":50,"code":"EPERM","path":"C:\\Work Bench\\WorkSpace\\Sprint22\\project_name\\app\\Backup"}
```

I dont know what I am missing its occurs randomly.

Thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 1):

You are not alone, I have found this problem too when I test my code in jasmine, and I have not been able to reproduce it in a more concise way. I would say it occurs with a 1% probability, it took a long time to isolate it :-)

It's not related to window explorer in my case. Immediately retrying after error works! Here is my application code to work around the problem:

```
try {
  fs.renameSync(oldDir, newDir);
}
catch (e) {
  fs.renameSync(oldDir, newDir);
}
```

It's as simple as that, that simplicity makes me think it's a bug in node.

I may have the same problem with rmdirSync issuing a false error too, but since it occurs in between interdependent async callbacks on the contrary of the renameSync problem, I won't be so affirmative.

I'm using node v5.3.0

Answer (score 0):

I observe the same issue with the synchronous commands on Windows
    fs.removeSync('folder');
    fs.mkdirsSync('folder');
The EPERM error seems to be thrown when an instance of the Windows explorer is opened and the 'folder' is displayed anywhere in the explorer. So far I found no solution except closing the explorer (and waiting a few seconds), which is very annoying...

Answer (score 0):

I have read the answer to a related problem [in this very nice post](http://www.daveeddy.com/2013/03/26/synchronous-file-io-in-nodejs/). In short, the Node doc is only giving you a close approximation (ie. it lies ;-) )  when its says that some file system things are done, either synchronously or asynchronously. Depending on the API you use, you have to wait a little bit before it is effectively done.

The information exposed there explains very well the "random bugs" in my code, including EPERM problems like you describe, and why retrying "immediately" an operation that just failed works (most of the time at least :-) )

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes some processes like AV software can lock the destination folder. The only way on Windows to prevent such an error is to repeat renaming.

You can use [graceful-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graceful-fs) package or implement a similar logic by yourself. Check how it's [solved in graceful-fs](https://github.com/isaacs/node-graceful-fs/blob/5a29f6c50ccdb412cb198b06ee248e65f365145b/polyfills.js#L83:L115)